# Command Button doesn't work when first clicked

Tags: excel, vba

All the programming I have learned is through manuals and websites such as this. So I wouldn't call myself a programmer but I do use a lot of quick and dirty macros to make my life easier. Occasionally, it all falls down and assistance is required!

I have a workbook that summarises the jobs I have worked on. In order to work quicker I have added a few command buttons too speed up simple tasks like filtering the blanks in a specific column. Normally this works OK. It is three weeks since I last used the workbook and today it is misbehaving. Click on a command button and the ribbon turns mostly grey. Click on the button again and the code runs and the ribbon returns to normal.

I have put a breakpoint in the code. On first click the breakpoint is not reached. On second click the breakpoint is reached!

Interestingly, if I click the command button the first time and then go into the vba editor and click on the break button the ribbon returns to normal again. So something is happening but it doesn't get as far as CommandButtonIssd_Click.

The command button code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonIssd_Click()
    FilterIt 9
End Sub
```

Most of the other command buttons just act on a different column number.

In the main module the code is:

```
Sub FilterIt(FieldNo As Integer)
'
' Filter Macro
'
    FilterOff
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=FieldNo, Criteria1:="="

End Sub

Sub FilterOff()
Dim a As Range, b As Range, iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
    
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then      'on, turn it off
        Set a = Selection                   'keep current location
        iRow = a.Row
        iCol = a.Column
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Range(Cells(iRow, iCol), Cells(iRow, iCol)).Select  'reset current location
    End If

End Sub
```

All this does is filter column 9 to show only the blank cells.

I am thinking that it's a Windows10, Office365 issue as the code has been stable for a while and it was working OK last time I used it. In which case, it's just a case of waiting for MS to sort it's bugs out and issue an update (every Thursday, regular as clockwork!).
OR my code is suspect and needs tweaking to stop it messing with the system.

You thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: So, all working OK today! Haven't changed any of the code.I suspect it was a typical Windows problem. Reboot and it goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today with an Excel 365 workbook: All CommandButtons would not fire on first click. They would fire on subsequent clicks, however.

> today it is misbehaving. Click on a command button and the ribbon turns mostly grey. Click on the button again and the code runs and the ribbon returns to normal.

In my case, the bad behavior disappeared when I closed and reopened Excel and then reopened the workbook. After that, CommandButtons fired upon first click. I concur with @MikeK that it appears to be an Excel bug.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally!**
Same problem, different workbook.
New laptop, Windows 11, Office 365 and I think I have a better definition of the problem as a little more information is now available.

If I open the spreadsheet on the laptop screen the macro and command buttons on the spreadsheet all work fine.

If set up the monitor screen as a duplicate of the laptop screen it all works OK.

If I set up the monitor screen as an extended display, then move the spreadsheet to the monitor screen and try again it fails as follows:

- Open the macro sheet and it loads OK on the monitor screen but the form with the menu on it is displayed on the laptop screen!?
- Exit the macro and it takes me to the macro spreadsheet and three command buttons as it should do.
- Click on "Open Contact List" and the spreadsheet content is replaced by plain black (or the contents of the underlying window!). Click again without moving the mouse and the (now invisible) button works and loads the contact list.
- close the contact list and the excel window continues to display incorrectly as above.
- click inside the excel window and all is restored.
- same applies to the other two buttons.

Shouldn't all this be handled by the windows system?

Previously I could deal with having to click a button twice to make it work. Now I have to click an invisible button!

If it is a Windows bug, how do I report it?